# Tool to build the software delivery page on our website

Tags: software-development, download-manager

I'm working in a dev team and we're now pushing our code to market, I need something to help me build the 'software download' page that every software house uses. We have a mix of JS/CSS apps and some C# which will be zipped or created as installers, our targets are Windows and Linux. There will be a small number of customers, <100 total, and <5 now. We need to support versions, ie have older versions still available, and also documentation and release notes.

In short I need a tool or platform that will let me upload my files/installers to a folder, pickup release notes and then put a nice front end on this so our customers get a good experience.